# HEAD inner tags showing in BODY tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I am building a website using the source files of a previous website I already built. My problem is that the tags that belong to the HEAD appear in the BODY in browsers inspectors (Firefox and Chrome). Here is my HEAD:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="<?php echo $lg; ?>">
 <head>
  <base href="<?php echo $cfg->getHostDirectory(); ?>assets/cpanel/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/favicon.ico">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/playfair-display.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/glyphicons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ts-css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/admin.css">
  <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/ts-jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/js-admin-create.js"></script>
  <title><?php echo $cfg->getTitle($fileName, $lg); ?></title>
</head>
```

For some reason, I do not understand these tags goes in the BODY at runtime.
I searched on the StackOverflow for solutions but I cannot find anything helpful.

**Update:**

[image: Chrome Browser inspector]

**Update:**
Here I see a weird duplicate that does not actually exist in the real file!!!
[image]

Comment: Don't show us the PHP. Show us the HTML.

Comment: "the tags that belong to the HEAD appear in the BODY" —Which ones? All of them? Starting with `<base>`?

Comment: Yes all of them. The PHP inside are just values read from an XML file. For example the TITLE tag get the title of the webpage.

Comment: The page render well. But there is no title showed on the browser. The TITLE tag appears in the BODY with the correct value. In the HEAD there is a duplicate META UTF-8 tag and a duplicate TITLE tag with the value "Untitled Document"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HAGLUmQ.png — I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: I do not understand the problem, because the original website does not have any.

Comment: Look at the HTML source code in the browser. Not the PHP on the server. Not the DOM Inspector.

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you want me to look?

Comment: The last screenshot you posted. You need to find that code that is generating that empty HTML document before the document you are looking at the PHP for.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a registration form action to another page (which processed the registration and told the user an email had been sent for them to complete the process) but this latter page appeared to show all the html tags as text!

I tracked it down to a set-up file I had required, which had set the header content-type to **application/json**, thereby causing the browser to try and treat the response as an AJAX type response rather than a page to be loaded.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when adding a custom `<jsdata>`-tag to my head. So I think it is due to your `<base>`-tag. In don't know why you need it but try deleting it or put it at the end of your head because only all the tags after your custom tag will be moved into the body.